# Fibonacci series up to 300 terms

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I tried to generate a list of Fibonacci numbers up to 300 terms and gets a runtime error.

```
f[0]=0;
f[1]=1;
f[x_]:=f[x-1]+f[x-2];
Table[f[x],{x,1,300}]
```

Is there any other way of solving this?